# Were there lobbyists in the closed-door meeting the night before the floor vote electing the new US Speaker? To whom is Rep. Tim Burchett referring?

Tags: united-states, congress, procedure, lobbying, speaker

In CNN's October 25, 2023 [GOP lawmaker says colleagues need to 'get off their butts and get to work](https://youtu.be/Ga7hRKJe6To) (an apparently tired) US representative [Tim Burchett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Burchett) discusses the closed door meeting that took place late at night before the floor vote the next day that elected the new House Speaker.

His comments include two references to lobbyists.

After 01:20

> I think what you have to understand about Mike Johnson is just who he is. This town is bucking, **and there is much gnashing of teeth and wringing of hands last night from the lobbyists and the special interests.** This town is languishing in moral and fiscal ambiguity, and he will restore that.

After 03:00

> And the other question I get asked was 'was it worth it'? (and I say) absolutely it was worth it. It was... as I've stated many times, I prayed about it, it was the right thing to to, and I think you're going to see a great leader.
>
> **I think the lobbyists are doing everything they can, as they did last night in our meeting,** you saw some of the old guard trying to rally support for a bogus write-in type situation, and that's why we forced the vote, an actual voice vote, a roll-call vote. So people had to stand up. And you saw everybody gathering around him at the podium.
>
> So I think we are on our way to electing a speaker, today, at noon.

As I mentioned, Rep. Burchett may have been a bit tired, apparently this interview took place after midnight (there's a reference to the vote "today, at noon") but I'm confused by "lobbyists are doing everything they can, as they did last night in our meeting". Does lobbyists refer to members of congress in the meeting acting in the manner of a lobbyist, or actual lobbyists in the meeting, or lobbyists not physically there but still wielding influence, or something else?